# Edit build.xml in android project to include facebook sdk.jar

Tags: android, eclipse, build-automation, facebook-login, build.xml

I'm editing the build.xml file in eclipse for the next release of a android project. In this sprint I added facebook login feature, so I refered facebook sdk as internal library. Now I want to edit the build.xml in order to include it. How can I do this?

I searched for previous questions here but couldn't find the exact answer I'm looking for. Can somebody explain this how to do this? Tnx in advance.

---

do I need to edit and add something to ant.properties file ? Any suggestions? Something like "add jar.libs.dir=your_path_here/lib in ant.properties for SDK >=8"...This also did no change BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to edit the build.xml in order to include it. How can I do this?

Please put your JAR in the `libs/` directory of your project. Ant will pick it up from there. No changes to `build.xml` are needed.

Comment: when I include the facebooksdk.jar in libs/ the project does not compile. error log shows this error.  "Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/AccessToken$SerializationProxyV1;"

Comment: this is because of you are using facebook_lib_project and a jar version of same in your project. Exclude one of them.

Comment: @AchiniSamuditha: If Facebook's SDK is an Android library project, not a JAR, follow the instructions for attaching the Android library project: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Comment: @PankajKumar I excluded the Facebook lib project as you said. and included only thefacebook.jar in /libs. But still my project cannot be compiled. What to do?

Comment: Clean your project, and refresh... or some time restarting the eclipse solves this problem..

Comment: @PankajKumar  cleaned and build the project again. it didn't worked. R is underlined everywhere